# how to add auto generated alphanumeric key in id_column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

What happens is a user comes on site, fills create a new product form with title, description, price et cetera fields...

I want to store a unique generated alphanumeric key in my 'id' column which is set to auto_increment by default, use that unique key as my product_id. Like every Youtube video has its own generated unique key rather than having id like *'1', '2', '3'....*

I'm generating that key using `"uniqid();"` **function**.

Please do let me know if I'm doing it wrong or there is better approach to do this. I'm a complete rookie.

Comment: Why do you want to use both auto-incremented database values, and `uniqid()`?

Comment: No, I just want to use the generated "uniqid();" values.

Comment: You basically take away the privilege from a column when you give it the type auto-increment. It defeats the purpose of being automatic if you're going to assign some value yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following two things cannot be true simultaneously:

- unique generated alphanumeric key
- 'id' column which is set to auto_increment by default

You cannot have a alphanumeric key which is auto_increment because by definition, alphanumeric means a string created with alphabets and numbers and you cannot auto increment alphabets, makes sense?

So my suggestion is that you leave the "id" key numeric as 1, 2, 3 etc and create one more column in your table, name it "unique_id" lets say. Of course you can name it whatever you like. It needs to be VARCHAR(255) type.

And then populate that column using following functions:

```
$bytes = 12;
$uniqueId = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)); //this will create 24 char alphanumeric string, you can increase or decrease it by changing the $bytes
```

and put this `$uniqueId` into your column and voila, you have your unique id of the entity.

**UPDATE**

In order to show the alphanumeric unique id in your url, you need to change  your url structure from `/localhost/product/product_id` to `/localhost/product/product_unique_id` and I am assuming you have somewhere your product listed with some kind of hyperlink, clicking on which takes user to the product detail page, right?

Let's say you had a product which has id 1 and unique id lt4Zhr7 so simply where you list products, you give the unique id of the product like so:

```
<a href="/localhost/product/lt4Zhr7"> Product 1 </a>
```

This is a basic solution which is supposed to guide you in the right direction, your actual code might be different based upon the framework you are using or some other factor.

Comment: How do I show that uniqueId in URL? When I create a product my URL is  "/localhost/product/product_id" e.g "/localhost/product/4". I want it to be like "/localhost/product/lt4Zhr7"

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It's a very reasonable solution. The uniqueid is as close as you can get to a truly unique, even cryptographically secure(which is way beyond the scope of the question but good none the less), random. And @Learner is right. There's no way you can have Auto increment AND string in the same column.

Comment: Thank you @Andrei . OP, I have updated my answer to give you an insight into how can you load your product using the unique id.

Comment: Thank you @Learner. But how do I add a prefix in openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() ?

Comment: Simple PHP concatenation? `$uniqueId = 'prefix_'.bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes));` That should work?

Comment: My good sir, @Learner, You are the man! One last thing, where do I update the route to show the unique_id in URL?

Comment: That depends on where you are redirecting the users to the "product detail" page. It depends upon the structure of your website.

Comment: Please post a separate question with it, giving other details relevant to this particular issue such as which Framework you are using and what is your website structure etc. This conversation is out of the scope of the original question asked. Thank you!